# While loop and reminders table

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have next code :

```
    <?php
session_start();
include("config.php");
global $kon;
ob_start();

//Uzimamo trenutni datum i vrijeme da mozemo spremiti u orders tabelu
$dt = new DateTime();
$trenutniDatum = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
$trenutniDatumiVrijeme = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');

$leeggoed = " ";

$rezWeek = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM weekelijks");
$brRez = mysqli_num_rows($rezWeek);

$korpa = "<table width=\"80%\">
          <tr align=\"center\">
            <th bgcolor=\"#E5E5E5\" style=\"padding:3px;\">Aantal</th>
            <th bgcolor=\"#E5E5E5\" style=\"padding:3px;\">Product</th>
          </tr>";

if($brRez > 0){
    while($redWeek = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezWeek)){
        $user_id = $redWeek["user_id"];

        //Uzimamo podatke za korisnika
        $rezKor = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE id = ". $user_id ." LIMIT 1");
        $redKor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezKor);
        $korEmail = $redKor["email"];
        $naam = $redKor["ime"] . $redKor["prezime"];

        //Sad moeamo uzeti cutoff id
        $rezCutoff = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT cutoffs.id as cutoff_id, cutoffs.datetime as cutoffTime, regios.id as regioID, regios.naam as regioNaam, regio_deelgemeente_tt.id, deelgemeentes.regio_postcode  
                                        FROM cutoffs 
                                        INNER JOIN regios ON regios.id = cutoffs.regio_id 
                                        INNER JOIN regio_deelgemeente_tt ON regios.id = regio_deelgemeente_tt.regio_id
                                        INNER JOIN deelgemeentes ON regio_deelgemeente_tt.deelgemeente_id = deelgemeentes.id 
                                        WHERE deelgemeentes.regio_postcode = ". $redKor["postcode"] ." GROUP BY cutoffs.regio_id");
        $redCutoff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezCutoff);

        //Otpakujemo datum da imamo lijep prikaz
        $datum_query = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM datetime) AS dan, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datetime) AS mjesec,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datetime) AS godina, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datetime) AS sat, EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM datetime) AS minute, EXTRACT(SECOND FROM datetime) AS sekunde FROM cutoffs WHERE id=". $redCutoff["cutoff_id"] ." ");
        $datum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datum_query);
        $dateCutOff = $datum["godina"] . "-" . $datum["mjesec"] . "-" . $datum["dan"];

        $trenutniDatum = strtotime($trenutniDatum);
        $cutOffDatum = strtotime($dateCutOff);

        //Uzimamo produkt po product_shop_id
        $rezProdShop = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT producten.*, producten.naam as prodNaam, shops.*, shops.id as shopId, shops.naam as shopNaam, product_shop_tt.* 
                                         FROM product_shop_tt INNER JOIN producten ON producten.id = product_shop_tt.product_id
                                         INNER JOIN shops ON shops.id = product_shop_tt.shop_id
                                         WHERE product_shop_tt.id = ". $redWeek["product_shop_tt_id"] ."");
        $redProdShop = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezProdShop);

        $korpa .= "<tr align=\"center\">
                    <td style=\"padding:3px;\">". $redWeek["aantal"] ."</td>
                    <td style=\"padding:3px;\">". $redProdShop["prodNaam"] ."</td>
                  </tr>"; 

        if($trenutniDatum == $cutOffDatum){
            $onsdMail = "info@boodschappen.be";
            $from = "Uwboodschappen - aankoop reminder";
            $to = $korEmail;
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
            $headers .= 'From:' . $from . "\r\n" .
                        'Reply-To: ' . $onsdMail . "\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

            $subject = "Aankoop reminder";
            $message = "Dag ". $naam .", <br /><br />";
            $message .= "". $korpa ."";
            $message .= "Met vriendelijke groeten, <br /><br />";
            $message .= "<a href=\"http://www.uwboodschappen.be\">Uw boodschappen</a><br />";
            $message .= "info@uwboodschappen.be";

        }

    }
    echo "</table>";

}else{
    exit(); 
}



ob_flush();

?>
```

I have one database table **weekelijks** (*id, user_id, product_shop_tt_id, aantal*).
I want to make a script for which I'll make cron. I think I know how to do that.
My table weekelijks is :
[image]

I want that my code use everything from that table and send it to the user. 
Now the code read all the data and all will be sent to all users. What I want is to read the data and that it is sent to the user whose id related to these products with user_id.
Now I get [image]

But I want : 
[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to batch up the output and only send it when the user id changes. You appear to be outputting data when a date field matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crudely knocked up and not tested but will hopefully give you the idea.

The following code loops through the records from your main table. For each one it passes the details to an object. The object takes care of doing the output when the user id changes, and also does the output when the destructor is called.

I have merged your sql for the main table with that to get the email details. I have abused GROUP BY to just get a single record for the emails, but this can (and probably should) be cleaned up.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");
global $kon;
ob_start();

//Uzimamo trenutni datum i vrijeme da mozemo spremiti u orders tabelu
$dt = new DateTime();
$trenutniDatum = strtotime($dt->format('Y-m-d'));
$trenutniDatumiVrijeme = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');

$leeggoed = " ";

$rezWeek = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT a.id,
                                        a.user_id,
                                        a.product_shop_tt_id,
                                        a.aantal,
                                        b.email, 
                                        b.ime, 
                                        b.prezime, 
                                        b.postcode
                                FROM weekelijks a
                                INNER JOIN korisnici b
                                ON a.user_id = b.id
                                GROUP BY a.id,
                                        a.user_id,
                                        a.product_shop_tt_id
                                        a.aantal
                                ORDER BY a.user_id");
$brRez = mysqli_num_rows($rezWeek);


if($brRez > 0)
{
    $output_details = new output_details($trenutniDatum);
    while($redWeek = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezWeek))
    {
        //Uzimamo podatke za korisnika
        $korEmail = $brRez["email"];
        $naam = $brRez["ime"] . $brRez["prezime"];

        //Sad moeamo uzeti cutoff id
        $rezCutoff = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT cutoffs.id as cutoff_id, cutoffs.datetime as cutoffTime, regios.id as regioID, regios.naam as regioNaam, regio_deelgemeente_tt.id, deelgemeentes.regio_postcode  
                                        FROM cutoffs 
                                        INNER JOIN regios ON regios.id = cutoffs.regio_id 
                                        INNER JOIN regio_deelgemeente_tt ON regios.id = regio_deelgemeente_tt.regio_id
                                        INNER JOIN deelgemeentes ON regio_deelgemeente_tt.deelgemeente_id = deelgemeentes.id 
                                        WHERE deelgemeentes.regio_postcode = ". $brRez["postcode"] ." GROUP BY cutoffs.regio_id");
        $redCutoff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezCutoff);

        //Otpakujemo datum da imamo lijep prikaz
        $datum_query = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM datetime) AS dan, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datetime) AS mjesec,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datetime) AS godina, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datetime) AS sat, EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM datetime) AS minute, EXTRACT(SECOND FROM datetime) AS sekunde FROM cutoffs WHERE id=". $redCutoff["cutoff_id"] ." ");
        $datum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datum_query);
        $dateCutOff = $datum["godina"] . "-" . $datum["mjesec"] . "-" . $datum["dan"];

        $cutOffDatum = strtotime($dateCutOff);

        //Uzimamo produkt po product_shop_id
        $rezProdShop = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT producten.*, producten.naam as prodNaam, shops.*, shops.id as shopId, shops.naam as shopNaam, product_shop_tt.* 
                                         FROM product_shop_tt INNER JOIN producten ON producten.id = product_shop_tt.product_id
                                         INNER JOIN shops ON shops.id = product_shop_tt.shop_id
                                         WHERE product_shop_tt.id = ". $redWeek["product_shop_tt_id"] ."");
        $redProdShop = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezProdShop);

        $korpa = "<tr align=\"center\">
                    <td style=\"padding:3px;\">". $redWeek["aantal"] ."</td>
                    <td style=\"padding:3px;\">". $redProdShop["prodNaam"] ."</td>
                  </tr>"; 

        $output_details->add_output($redWeek, $korpa, $cutOffDatum);

    }

    unset ($output_details);

}
else
{
    exit(); 
}



ob_flush();

class output_details
{
    private $current_user = 0;
    private $naam = '';
    private $korpa = '';
    private $trenutniDatum = '';

    function __construct($trenutniDatum)
    {
        $this->trenutniDatum = $trenutniDatum;
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->do_output();
    }

    function add_output($redWeek, $korpa, $cutOffDatum)
    {
        if ($redWeek['user_id'] != $this->current_user)
        {
            $this->do_output();
            $this->current_user = $redWeek['user_id'];
            $this->korpa = "<table width=\"80%\">
                      <tr align=\"center\">
                        <th bgcolor=\"#E5E5E5\" style=\"padding:3px;\">Aantal</th>
                        <th bgcolor=\"#E5E5E5\" style=\"padding:3px;\">Product</th>
                      </tr>";       
        }
        if(this->trenutniDatum == $cutOffDatum)
        {
            $this->korpa .= $korpa;
        }
    }

    function do_output()
    {
        if ($this->current_user != 0)
        {
            $onsdMail = "info@boodschappen.be";
            $from = "Uwboodschappen - aankoop reminder";
            $to = $korEmail;
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
            $headers .= 'From:' . $from . "\r\n" .
                        'Reply-To: ' . $onsdMail . "\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

            $subject = "Aankoop reminder";
            $message = "Dag ". $this->naam .", <br /><br />";
            $message .= "". $this->korpa ."</table>";
            $message .= "Met vriendelijke groeten, <br /><br />";
            $message .= "<a href=\"http://www.uwboodschappen.be\">Uw boodschappen</a><br />";
            $message .= "info@uwboodschappen.be";

        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kickstart. I did something like that. I would like to send mail for example 14 hours before the date in the database weekelijks table. How could I do that. How should I set up cron and how to make it in the code to send for exemple 14 hours before the date in the database?

Comment: You would probably need to set up a regular CRON, depending on how accurate you need it to be for 14 hours before. When the CRON runs check if it is 14 hours before (or between 13 hours and 14 hours before) and that one hasn't already run. If OK then output the email and save a record on a table saying it has been output.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
session_start();
include("config.php");
global $kon;
ob_start();

//Uzimamo trenutni datum i vrijeme da mozemo spremiti u orders tabelu
$dt = new DateTime();
$trenutniDatum = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
$trenutniDatumiVrijeme = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');

$leeggoed = " ";

$rezWeek = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM weekelijks GROUP BY user_id");
$brRez = mysqli_num_rows($rezWeek);

if($brRez > 0){
    while($redWeek = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezWeek)){

        $user_id = $redWeek["user_id"];

        //Uzimamo podatke za korisnika
        $rezKor = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE id = ". $user_id ." LIMIT 1");
        $redKor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezKor);
        $korEmail = $redKor["email"];
        $naam = $redKor["ime"] . " " . $redKor["prezime"];

        $message = "Dag ". $naam .", <br /><br />";
        $message .= "Ovdje ide poruka <br /><br />";
        $message .= "<table style=\"max-width:100%;\">
                      <tr align=\"center\">
                        <th bgcolor=\"#E5E5E5\" style=\"padding:3px;\">Aantal</th>
                        <th bgcolor=\"#E5E5E5\" style=\"padding:3px;\">Product</th>
                        <th bgcolor=\"#E5E5E5\" style=\"padding:3px;\">Winkel</th>
                      </tr>";

        /****************Listanje produkata za ovog usera**********************/
        $rezTabela = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM weekelijks WHERE user_id = ". $redWeek["user_id"] ."");
        $brRezKor = mysqli_num_rows($rezTabela);

        //Ovdje listamo proizvode za ovog klanta
        while($redTabela = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezTabela)){
            //Uzimamo produkt po product_shop_id
            $rezProdShop = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT producten.*, producten.naam as prodNaam, shops.*, shops.id as shopId, shops.naam as shopNaam, product_shop_tt.* 
                                             FROM product_shop_tt INNER JOIN producten ON producten.id = product_shop_tt.product_id
                                             INNER JOIN shops ON shops.id = product_shop_tt.shop_id
                                             WHERE product_shop_tt.id = ". $redTabela["product_shop_tt_id"] ."");
            $redProdShop = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezProdShop);


            $message .= "<tr align=\"center\">
                            <td style=\"padding:3px;\">". $redTabela["aantal"] ."</td>
                            <td style=\"padding:3px;\">". $redProdShop["prodNaam"] ."</td>
                            <td style=\"padding:3px;\">
                                <a href=\"http://www.uwboodschappen.be/winkel-details.php?id=". $redProdShop["shopId"] ."\" title=\"Bezoek deze winkel\">
                                    <img src=\"upload/shops-logos/". $redProdShop["shopId"] .".jpg\" style=\"max-height:50px;\" alt=\"". $redProdShop["shopNaam"] ."\" title=\"". $redProdShop["shopNaam"] ."\">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr><br />";
        }
        /*****************************Kraj listanja produkata**************************************/
        $message .= "</table><br /><br />";
        $message .= "Met vriendelijke groeten,<br /><br />";
        $message .= "<a href=\"http://www.uwboodschappen.be\">Uwboodschappen.be</a><br />";
        $message .= "info@uwboodschappen.be";

        echo $message . "<br /><br /><br />";
    }


}else{
    exit(); 
}



ob_flush();

?>
```